# Access Computer's Default AppData Folder

Tags: c#, wpf, special-folders

I am currently trying to use the following to access a computer's local *AppData* folder:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
```

This returns something along the lines of `C:\\Users\\[USERNAME]\\AppData\\Roaming`. What I want is to get the default *AppData* folder, as opposed to any specific user's folder.

I can hard code this `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local`, but I'd feel more comfortable if there was a function that provided what I'm looking for.

Is there such a function, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` will get what you need.

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx):

> The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data that is used by all users.

Comment: Not what I was originally looking for, but I can now see that this is a better solution. Thank you.

Comment: To make it more clear, `CommonApplicationData` resolves to `C:\ProgramData`, not to`C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local`

Comment: Thanks @yurislav, but I think the idea is that the exact path is platform- and/or configuration-dependent. It can vary from machine to machine, but if you use this constant then your files will end up where they're supposed to be.